# How to access Google Family Link from within child device?

Tags: android-11, google-family-link

I want to install an application directly from .apk file on my child's phone. This operation is blocked due to the fact that the device is controlled by a parent.

On my child's phone I have an application called "Parental Control" installed. It is clearly from Google (help icon points to Google resources) though I have no idea what is it and how does it differs from Google Family Link.

Tapping (?) icon in the top-right corner opens a Family Link help where I can read (in "Unlock your child's device" section):

> 1. On your child's device, click **Parent Access**.
> 2. Enter the password for the parent's account used to supervise the child.

The problem is that I cannot find even a trace of "Parent Access" button or menu item. Neither in this "Parental Control" nor anywhere within the system (Readme 9A, Android 11).

Trying to resolve the above, in addition to this "Parental Control", I have also installed "the original" (?) Google Family Link app (also on child's phone). But when I am trying to run it, I am falling into a never-ending loop of:

1. Welcome to Family Link
2. Continue as [child name] (button)
3. The Family Link app is for parents
4. Parent sign-in (button)
5. Welcome to Family Link

I don't know what am I missing or doing wrong.

**How can I access "parent mode" in Google Family Link-supervised child's phone? Or temporarily disable this supervision? How can I install some third-party application directly from .apk file on Google Family Link-supervised device?**

This Redmi 9A phone is used as a spare device when the actual phone (Redmi 11S) is being repaired. But I recall that I had exactly the same problems (i.e. never-ending loop in Google Family Link) on Redmi 11S.

Answer (score 1):

To gain access to "Parent Access", lock child's device from Family Link app on your own device then you'll see the "Parent Access" button on lock screen of your child's device(See attached screenshot I got from Internet).
BTW, Family Link app is for parents while "Parental Control" is available on supervised devices.
[image: screenshot form Internet]